# flutter_emulator_device_problem

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-virtual-device

when i want to use emulator device in android studio for flutter app I get this error :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'D:\flutter project\untitled5\android\settings.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Google
  MavenRepo
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1